# How to feed images to Keras model that have multiple inputs with tf.data.Dataset generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When the model has only one input, I used *tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory* method to feed images and labels. If the model has two or more inputs like the following model, how to feed them with *tf.data.Dataset* generator or better way?

```python
# One input
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(...)
model.fit(dataset)

# Two or more inputs?
```

[image: example model]